# is it possible to scan the android classpath for annotations?

Tags: java, android

I want to scan the classpath for certain annotations in Android.

I have only found one solution to this problem: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/737/android-hacks-scan-android-classpath/

And as the author writes this solution works, but has several limitations. Are there any future-proof ways of doing this in android? Any libraries providing this functionality?

Comment: I'd love to see this question answered. I'm, currently, attempting to solve the exact same issue. The annotation scanning framework I've used in the past is Reflections (http://code.google.com/p/reflections/), but I can't quite figure out how to properly "point it" at the compiled code-base...

Comment: I can only think of letting Reflections scan the annotations at compile time and generate an XML file with that information (which it does, in fact, support), and then load all the info from that file at runtime (see the bottom of the project page and http://code.google.com/p/reflections/wiki/ReflectionsMojo for details)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using android 3.0

```
public static <T extends Annotation> List<Class> getClassesAnnotatedWith(Class<T> theAnnotation){

    // In theory, the class loader is not required to be a PathClassLoader
    PathClassLoader classLoader = (PathClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Field field = null;
    ArrayList<Class> candidates = new ArrayList<Class>();

    try {
        field = PathClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("mDexs");
        field.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // nobody promised that this field will always be there
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get mDexs field", e);
    }

    DexFile[] dexFile = null;
    try {
        dexFile = (DexFile[]) field.get(classLoader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get DexFile", e);
    }

    for (DexFile dex : dexFile) {
      Enumeration<String> entries = dex.entries();
      while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        // Each entry is a class name, like "foo.bar.MyClass"
        String entry = entries.nextElement();

        // Load the class
        Class<?> entryClass = dex.loadClass(entry, classLoader);
        if (entryClass != null && entryClass.getAnnotation(theAnnotation) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Found: " + entryClass.getName());
            candidates.add(entryClass);
        }
      }
    }

    return candidates;
}
```

I also created one to determin if a class was derived from X

```
public static List<Class> getClassesSuperclassedOf(Class theClass){

    // In theory, the class loader is not required to be a PathClassLoader
    PathClassLoader classLoader = (PathClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Field field = null;
    ArrayList<Class> candidates = new ArrayList<Class>();

    try {
        field = PathClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("mDexs");
        field.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // nobody promised that this field will always be there
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get mDexs field", e);
    }

    DexFile[] dexFile = null;
    try {
        dexFile = (DexFile[]) field.get(classLoader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get DexFile", e);
    }

    for (DexFile dex : dexFile) {
      Enumeration<String> entries = dex.entries();
      while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        // Each entry is a class name, like "foo.bar.MyClass"
        String entry = entries.nextElement();

        // Load the class
        Class<?> entryClass = dex.loadClass(entry, classLoader);
        if (entryClass != null && entryClass.getSuperclass() == theClass) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Found: " + entryClass.getName());
            candidates.add(entryClass);
        }
      }
    }

    return candidates;
}
```

enjoy - B

Comment: As you might have noticed, this is basically the same code I added in the link. I am using it and it seems to work, but it is very experimental. Anyways, thanks for the answer (and although it seems to work fine) not the ideal solution I was looking for.